# Following code is not working as expected in DEV C++

Tags: c++

The following code is not working in DEV C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    cout << "Hello world";
}
```

How can I do this?

Also, tell me if I can get almost all the functionality of Turbo C++ in Dev C++. Also, tell me if I can easily switch to DEV C++ if I know a moderate amount in Turbo C++. I just want to use C++ with Python 3.x for console applications including GUI.

Comment: Define "not working" - do you get compilation errors? If yes, post them here

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: There is no output seen in the output window when I use cout statement. But, the output is seen when I use the printf statement.

Comment: Turbo C++‽ Wow that's old. I'm sorry if your teacher is forcing you to use that. If possible, switch to clang or gcc or Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, which are all free.

Comment: Just tell me whether DEV C++ is ok or not! Please. I just want to use it with Python 3.x.

Comment: Technically, `void main()` is not a thing in C++. Not sure that is your problem, though.

Comment: Since "not working" has not been clarified by way of a question edit, I will try to close this question. You are most welcome and encouraged to improve the question to one that is more understandable and specific. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your initial question (`printf` works while `ostream` doesn't) the problem may be in buffering. Try that:

```
std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
```

or, if you wish to avoid a newline:

```
std::cout << "Hello world";
std::cout.flush();
```

There is a difference between streams and `printf`: the streams are not outputing the data immediately but buffer that to optimize the performance. This however means that in some environments for the small outputs like yours it may stuck forever waiting for more output.

Comment: Ok! that works. Thanks. Now, tell me if I can expect to easily switch to DEV C++ or any of the new compilers like GCC if I know a moderate amount of Turbo C++.

Comment: @Abhijeet.py I don't see any obstacles in switching to a newer compiler. The opposite may be true: using the old compiler may be very annoying.

Comment: @Abhijeet.py and please revery your changes in the question: after your edit you lost the core part of it: the difference between buffered and unbuffered output.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I just wanted to use a mixture of Python 3.x and C++. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

I used *int main* instead of *void main*.

Comment: Tell me why the void main() is not working?

Comment: Well, int main()  returns a value, and it is preferred in comparison to void main() since void main()  it's not accepted by many standards. I don't use void main() so I don't know much else.